# Old game - platformer, dinosaurs, woman protagonist

Tags: story-identification, video-games, dinosaurs, female-characters

Definitely a PC side scrolling platformer with a female main character. I think she fights dinosaurs but I could be wrong, maybe there are some lizards or big birds.
From the way I remember graphics it could be 1993-1994 but maybe it is a later game designed to look this way. Almost definitely from 1990's anyway.
Better graphics than Jungle Jill and Entity. Not anything like Dino Crysis as well.
I don't think it was a very famous or successful game.
Faint memory-sorry for poor description but that is why I can't locate it myself.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIIRtWPYBtg matches, but it's a MegaDrive game

Comment: Having solved it, you should put that as a self-answer. We're not really here to offer recommendations though.